# XMLRPC Wordpress Image Upload - Uploads Empty Image?

Tags: java, android, wordpress, base64, xml-rpc

I am trying to upload an image file to a Wordpress Site using XMLRPC. 
I'm using org.apache.xmlrpc:xmlrpc-client to make the connection from Android, and I can successfully hit the website, and fire the upload, but the image file is empty on the site. I've sent through a base64 encoded string as the WP API states but I just can't get it to work?

Anyone know why?
This is my code:

```
public static void updatePhoto(final String status, final Context context, final String uri) {

    websiteUrl = (String) loadPreference("wordpressUrl", context,String.class);
    username = (String) loadPreference("wordpressUsername", context,String.class);
    password = (String) loadPreference("wordpressPassword", context,String.class);

    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            try {
                XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
                config.setServerURL(new URL(websiteUrl+"/xmlrpc.php"));

                XmlRpcClient rpcClient = new XmlRpcClient();
                rpcClient.setConfig(config);

                Uri realUri = getImageContentUri(context,Uri.parse(uri).getPath());

                final InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(realUri);
                Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                originalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] outputByteArray = baos.toByteArray();

                String base64EncodedString = Base64.encodeToString(outputByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

                Map content = new Hashtable();
                content.put("name", status+".jpg");
                content.put("type", "image/jpeg");
                content.put("bits", base64EncodedString);
                content.put("overwrite", false);


                // Make the XMLRPC call.
                Object result = rpcClient.execute("wp.uploadFile", new Object[]{
                        0,
                        username,
                        password,
                        content
                });

                // Print result - this is the new post's ID.
                System.out.println(result);

            } catch (final XmlRpcException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });

}

public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, String absPath) {
    Log.v(TAG, "getImageContentUri: " + absPath);

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            , new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID }
            , MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? "
            , new String[] { absPath }, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI , Integer.toString(id));

    } else if (!absPath.isEmpty()) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, absPath);
        return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private static String encodeImage(Bitmap bm)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    return encImage;
}
```

Comment: I've seen issues with mime-type & xmlrpc. A guess, but try `image/jpg` vs `image/jpeg`

Comment: @hwl thanks for the reply. I tried this, apparently image/jpg isn't a real mime type!